# Magento 2 - Categories in Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation, category-tree, category-attribute

My layered navigation is not displaying categories in a filterable manner, screenshot below.

[image]

Currently every category in my tree is set to anchor and when I go to a given category page, all the products associated with the child categories are displaying in the grid but all that is displaying in the sidebar are links to the immediate child categories pages; the list of categories isn't collapsable either. Moreover, when I load the category page, it indicates the parent category is selected.

Comment: Please let me know if you find any solution, I am also having same requirement !!!